# How to handle child objects extension in Apollo Federation

Tags: graphql, apollo-federation

Service A:

```
type A {
  id: ID!
  embeddedMetaData: MetaData
}
type MetaData{
  fieldA: String
}
```

Service B:

```
type A  @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID! @external
  #I want to extend and resolve a new field into MetaData type without overriding
}
```

How can I extend embedded object without overriding any other fields and leaving the resolution of the other fields in the A service?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend type A in service B, by first making type A extendable:

Service A

```
type A @key(fields: "id") {
 id: ID!
  embeddedMetaData: MetaData
}
type MetaData{
 fieldA: String
}
```

Type A is now an entity.
You can add new fields on type A that will be resolved by service B following below:

Service B

```
extend type A  @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID! @external
  newField: String
}
```

Comment: For type A yes, but I want to Extend the "MetaData" type in B.